# Screwturn wiki to point to existing database will not work

Tags: installation, screwturn

I recently moved my screwturn installation to a completely new environment (site on new IIS/server and database moved to new SQL Server).
I can succesfully open the Screwturn wiki but instead of using the existing database (that I configured in the web.config), Screwturn wants to create the DB from scratch and hence states the error that certain tables already exist in the DB.
If I create a blank DB and use this in the web.config, Screwturn will happily create its tables and use that DB.  Of course, that's not what I want, I want it to use the existing, moved DB on the server.
Is there a way to tell Screwturn not to create the DB and simply "use" the existing one?
If this is not possible, are there scripts available to copy the content from the old DB to the new one (simply copying it with SQL Servers Import/Export feature gives errors (logical) that certain fields cannot be created as that will cause PK violations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use your old web.config or just update the SQL connection info in the web.config from the new version?  I think you should use your old web.config (maybe compare to the new one to see if anything was added).  I have done this several times with several installations and haven't had a problem.

The only other thing I can think of off-hand is if your old version is v2, then you should review the instructions here as a few things changed from v2 to v3.

[Old Screwturn Wiki Site - Upgrade from v2 to v3](http://web.archive.org/web/20120903072240/http://www.screwturn.eu/Help.UpgradeFromV2.ashx)

Comment: Hi Doug, it's not an upgrade and I indeed just copy-pasted the web.config from the old location to the new (and modified the SQL connection parameters to point to the new SQL).